# what is key and secret in oauth python

Tags: python, oauth, key, linkedin-api

I am very new to python (just know the syntax) and oauth (from Wiki page). I want to get oauth token from linkedin and then use it for further API calls. I went through http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-oauth-token-python but did not understand few things like KEY and SECRET (what are those and what should I pass there). Can anyone please help me on this? Also I am unable to find a sample python file which does the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @moe-jan describes the client id (api key) and secret (secret key) from [your application page](https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer) are used for client authentication.

Note that LinkedIn is migrating to OAuth 2 (your example uses OAuth 1). If you would like to do the same you can re-use the same client/consumer id and secret from OAuth 1 and see an example of how to obtain a token in this [LinkedIn OAuth 2 example](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/linkedin.html).

The example uses code not yet released on PyPI (as of this writing) but can be installed with

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib.git#egg=requests_oauthlib
```

Answer (score 2):

LinkedIn (like many sites) use api keys and secrets to track who is using their API and how they use it.  It helps them be sure that their API isn't being used maliciously.  Your api key is called a `consumer_key` and your api secret is called a `consumer secret` in this example

Your `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` can be obtained by registering as a LinkedIn developer.

You can register by clicking the register link on [this page](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication)

After you get your api key and api secret you can plug those two in as string variables in the example you linked. From there it's really straightforward.

Comment: Thanks a lot Moe Jan. I just learned about adding app to linkedin and getting oauth_token key and secret. Soon I will try to use that token for different APIs.

Comment: No problem, but just so you know that token will not work for "different" API's it will only for LinkedIn's.

Comment: hehe..that is what I wanted to convey. Anyways, thanks again..!
:)